# Using custom JQuery in Rails Admin [rails 6]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, rails-admin

My application uses 'rails_admin' and I would like every page within '/admin' to have a custom javascript file.

rails version: 6

EDIT:

[My example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKyvn.png)
I want to remove all these comments on each model, when I go to 'add new'.

All of these are `<span class = 'help-block'>...</span>`
so I thought about using `document.getElementsByClassName("help-block").style.visibility = "hidden";` it to solve my problem.

But it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails admin has a way to remove those "comments" for example if you place this code any of your models

```
rails_admin do
  edit do
    field :name do
      help do
        nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Its kind of annoying to do it for every field, but repetition in configuration is one of rails_admin weaknesses

Comment: Got this error: 
undefined method `help' for #<RailsAdmin::Config::Sections::Edit:0x0000000008d1a080>

Comment: Lol, now it works!. Probably, some sintax error in my code.... Dunno... haha.
But thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Create this file on your project directory, create the folders if needed:

```
/app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/ui.js
```

Then place this content on the file

```
//= require_tree .
let yourjavascript = 'whatever you want'
```

Rails admin will import it this file on every page.

You might need to clear your assets pipeline depending on your configuration

```
rake tmp:clear
```

Comment: Okay, that's work, but doens't solve my problem has i thought. I gonna edit the question

Comment: I added a new solution for your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

To turn off the 'comments' for the whole model, use the following code in your rails_admin.rb file:

```
config.model "ModelName" do

  edit do
    fields do
      help false
    end
  end

end
```